# identify longest range of non-blank contiguous cells in a row

Tags: excel, vba, range, contiguous, nonblank

I have an Excel spreadsheet of velocity values (see link below) with some blanks interspersed. I am trying to loop through each row and return the range of the longest set of contiguous non-blank cells in each row. I will ultimately use the range address to perform other functions (i.e., average the values within this range). I have used the code below to count the number of columns in a range before, but haven't figured out how to count only non-blank cells and continue counting in the same row.

`ColumnCount = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

[About the image: The highlighted columns represent depth & ensemble numbers, and the non-highlighted values represent velocity values that I would like to process. This spreadsheet continues for another 2,0000 columns. There's a lot of data!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1ZNU.png)

Thank you! Any help would be much appreciated!
Marie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Do Until` loop and `If` statements to traverse the entire row from beginning to the end. Below is the example for one row (doesn't have Excel at the moment, so cannot check). `maxLength` variable stores maximium found at each iteration. `Cells(1, currCol).Value = ""` used to check whether the continuous range consists of only 1 cell (otherwise, it would count empty range plus 2 nonempty cells plus 1 more cell).

```
Dim maxLength as Integer
maxLength = 0
currCol = 1
totalCol = Columns.Count
If Cells(1, currCol).Value = "" Then
    currCol = Cells(1, currCol).End(xlToRight).Column
End If
Do Until currCol = totalCol
    prevCol = currCol
    If Cells(1, prevCol + 1).Value = "" Then
        maxLength = WorkSheetFunction.Max(maxLength, 1)
    Else
        currCol = Cells(1, currCol).End(xlToRight).Column
        maxLength = WorkSheetFunction.Max(maxLength, currCol - prevCol + 1)
    End if
    currCol = Cells(1, currCol).End(xlToRight).Column
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I fixed one typo in WorksheetFunction, but it is also giving me an application-defined or object-defined error for the second to last line "currCol = Cells...". and won't let the code run. Any thoughts on why this error is coming up?

Comment: Can you provide your file or a screenshot of the sheet you're dealing with?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include a link with a screenshot! Hope that helps explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It was due to another one typo I made: `currColl` instead of `currCol` was written. Corrected.

Comment: Amazing! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @mariec123, if the answer helped you solve your problem, then mark it as answer. It will be helpful for others to instantly see that the question has an answer.